# Launch Spyder from Windows Explorer

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I want to know how to launch Spyder for my `.py` files. Currently, I have to go all over anaconda navigator and select spyder to launch so I made a shortcut to spyder in the Start Menu.

I have tried the Open with   `Path\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder.exe`  methods but just shows a command prompt for half a second and then exits.

While browsing I saw something about the envs folder in anaconda folder but its empty right now

```
Versions
Window 10,
condo 4.8.3,
Spyder 4.1.4
```

Comment: Pressing window key and type spyder then right-click on the spyder and open with the administrator option. I do it in this way.

Comment: Show what you actually tried rather than describing it. I have no idea what "the open with path..." means

Comment: Open with method was one of the solutions given in some threads Path is the path to the anaconda folder

Comment: Imran the run as administrator option just launches the IDE that is the same as the shortcut in Start Menu. I want .py files to directly launch spyder

Answer (score 0):

Open a text file called spyder and paste this

```
C:\path\anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\path\anaconda3\cwp.py C:\path\anaconda3 C:\path\anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\path\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

make sure you fix the path to your anaconda3 install. Then save the txt file and change spyder.txt to spyder.bat

rightclick .py file and choose open with and pick spyder.bat (Remember to select always use this app to open this kind of file)

Comment: Just tried this but it is same as the Open with method. Command prompt pops and exits

Comment: I tried it and it works for me. Spyder starts when I double-click .py files, However, this is not something you should do anyway since you should be using different environments. Adding a bat file like this will always start spyder in your base environment which you should not be working in. It's better to start spyder in the environment you want to use and then open the .py files in spyder.